# How to prevent eyestrain?

Tags: brightness

For the following months, i'm going to work at home and will spend most of my time in front of my computer. 
Currently, i work on my computer more than 8 hours a day. (10h-14h on screens daily)

I've got a 15.6 inch laptop and a 23 inch screen on my PC. Except getting dark themes on editors and randomly lower brightness, i don't have any big clues to avoid eyes fatigue.

Just asking you guys, if you got couple of tips to avoid me future headaches !!

PS : 
-i'm wearing glasses for Myopia-Astigmatism.
-sorry if my english is bad

Comment: Color/gamma correction, lowering brightness, redshift, and just taking breaks will help. There are too many possible "answers" for this though, and they are primarily opinion based, as not all eyes are equal. Best option would probably be to talk to your optometrist or ophthalmologist about your needs.

Comment: Thanks I'm suppose to have glasses which reduce blue light already , but i never really talk about eyes strain with my optometrist in fact.

Answer (score 7):

Use [Redshift](http://jonls.dk/redshift/), a program much like [f.lux](https://justgetflux.com/), that can reduce the blue-ness of the screen as soon as the sun has set. This makes your display more suitable for nighttime activities, as the color of the screen matches those of the lights around you (orange/reddish 3200K), instead of the sun (lightblue 6000K).

I use it every day and I think it has helped me reduce eyestrain for a long time now.